# Количество вхождений строки в текст. Порядок слов в строке может изменятся, но это будет одним вхождением

Tags: java

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с задачей: посчитать количество вхождений слов, cтоящих рядом, но порядок слов в "вхождении" может меняться.
Например, у нас есть строка "мама мыла раму".
"раму мама мыла", "мыла раму мама" и т.д. - это все одно вхождение.
Надо посчитать сколько раз такие вхождение встретятся в тексте.

Текст для примера:
 Сегодня мама мыла раму. Мама мыла очень тщательно. Если бы раму мама мыла плохо - папа бы стал ругаться.

Получается вхождений 2 - "мама мыла раму" и "раму мама мыла

Как реализовать такой алгоритм средствами java? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Не вполне ясно, что именно вам нужно. Посчитать кол-во предложений, в которые входят **все** слова из данного списка? Или посчитать кол-во вхождений в текст для каждого из слов и найти минимум этих количеств? Если добавить к вашему тексту, напр. `Оконную раму, имеется в виду.` , то результат по-прежнему должен быть 2 или должен стать 3? Советую переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы в нем не было этой двусмысленности.

Comment: По прежнему останется 2 вхождения, слова должны стоять рядом. Их порядок может изменятся, но других слов между ними не должно быть. Спасибо, я поправил формулировку!

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Нужно найти все такие сочетания? Максимальное количество вхождений? Максимальное количество слов в группах, которые повторяются больше одного раза?

Comment: В строке надо найти количество (сумму) всех таких вхождений. Давайте еще пример приведу, на цифрах, возможно вы лучше меня поймете. 

Подстрока 1 2 3 (1 3 2, 2 1 3, 2 3 1, 3 1 2, 3 2 1) - это все берется за одну подстроку.

Строка **1 2 3** 4  5 **3 2 1** 4 3 2 **2 1 3** **1 3 2** 5 **3 2 1**

Итого у нас 5 вхождений подстроки 123 в строку

Comment: Все равно еще остаётся неоднозначность :) `1 2 3 2 1` -- одно вхождение или два?

Comment: Два. Спасибо за терпение и вашу внимательность ))

Comment: Грубо говоря, у нас есть рамка. Например размерности 3. В нее входит 3 слова - подстрока. Берем строку, в ней берем первые 3 слова (1 2 3), если слова совпадают(в любом их сочетании),  то инкрементируем. Потом берем слова, стоящие на позициях (2 3 4) и тоже их проверяем с подстрокой. Совпадает - инкрементируем

Comment: Простите, но все равно не до конца ясно. Повторяющаяся строка всегда одна и та же или нужно найти любую строку, которая больше остальных повторяется?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно сработать, можно подставлять любую комбинацию слов.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"мама", "мыла", "раму"};
    String text = "Сегодня мама мыла раму. Мама мыла очень тщательно. Если бы раму мама мыла раму плохо - папа бы стал ругаться.";

    int count = calculateCount(array, text);

    System.out.println(count);
}

private static int calculateCount(String[] array, String text) {
    String currentPattern = getPattern(array, "|");

    String finalPattern = getPattern(Collections.nCopies(array.length, currentPattern).toArray(new String[array.length]), " ");

    if (finalPattern.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(finalPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (matcher.find(i)) {
        count++;
        i = matcher.start() + 1;
    }

    return count;
}

private static String getPattern(String[] array, String delimiter) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter, "(", ")"));
}
```

Comment: Привет! Да, круто, оно работает, спасибо!
Но единственное - оно не считает тот случай, если у нас одно слово для двух вхождений. Возможно, я слишком поздно это написал в комментариях и вы не заметили.

Comment: Что значит одно слово для двух вхождений? Приведите пример.

Comment: Например, если подстрока 1 2 3 и строка 1 2 3 2 1 . То у нас два вхождения - 1 2 3 и 3 2 1. Спасибо.

Comment: В таком случае немного допишется код. Код выше иже изменен с вашими дополнительными условиями.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы меня очень выручили!

Comment: если тестировать со строкой 1 2 3 2 1 , то он почему-то находит 3 вхождения строки 1 2 3, хотя их 2. Спасибо

Comment: Их вообще-то три (1 2 3) 2 1 | 1 (2 3 2) 1 | 1 2 (3 2 1)

Comment: 2 3 2 - это не набор из сочетаний 1 2 3

Comment: Строка 2 3 2  будет относится к подстроке  2 2 3 (2 3 2 , 3 2 2 )

Answer (score 0):

Создайте словарь, содержащий пары - ключ-слово из списка, значение - счетчик.

Пройдите по списку слов окном нужной длины (здесь 3).

На каждом шаге одно слово выходит из окна - если оно из списка - уменьшить соответствующий счетчик. Одно слово входит в окно - если оно из списка - увеличить соответствующий счетчик.

Если счетчик становится равным 1, то увеличить NumWords. Если счетчик переходит из 1 в другое состояние - уменьшить NumWords.

Если NumWords равно длине фразы (все счетчики равны 1) - найдено вхождение фразы.